# Back button works, but the actionbar button does not?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a pretty simple use case which seems to be working for all my Activities except one.  All my Activities are calling `getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);`.  The only place this isn't working is on an Activity I just added, which is also the only one I'm launching from the main activity's info menu.  The actual OS back button works as expected in this case, but the Home button is not.  Here's the menu logic that starts the activity:

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch(item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.share:
                share();
                return true;
            case R.id.support:
                emailSupport();
                return true;
            case R.id.settings:
                settings();
                return true;
            case android.R.id.home: 
                onBackPressed();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

The problem is with the `SettingsActivity`, called in the menu by the `settings()` method you see in the switch above:

```
private void settings(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(InfoMenuActivity.this, SettingsActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

And the `onCreate` of the `SettingsActivity` is pretty simple too:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
    prefs = this.getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.preference_file), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    setView();
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
}
```

I originally only had the first `getActionBar()` call, but added the second to see if it changed anything, but it did not.

What am I missing?

Comment: In android Manifest file have you defined parent activity of this Activity?

Comment: No, but I haven't done that for any of them.  I'll give it a try, though, thanks.

Comment: actually from the docs it looks like htat's not supported until Android 4.1, but I'm supporting farther back than that.

Comment: Try to give the parent activity in manifest file hope it will work.

Comment: As I said, i can't w/o changing the version support which I'd prefer not to do.

Comment: ? I don't understand what you're suggesting. It also doesn't make sense that I have to handle this differently from the other ~20 or so Activities that I have that are working fine. Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments it seems that you don't know how to set the parent activity in the manifest and keep supporting older versions.

For API 16 you can use `parentActivityName` attribute but for older versions you'll have to add a meta tag:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.SettingsActivity"
    android:label="Settings Activity"
    android:parentActivityName="com.example.MainActivity" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value="com.example.MainActivity" />
</activity>
```

If all you want to do is override the up button functionality to act as a back button then don't forget that in *every activity* you'll have to override `onOptionsItemSelected`.

However remember that overriding any **default and expected** android behaviour is bad practice.

Comment: That still requires min SDK 16, I get an error on the manifest if I keep my min SDK at 15.

Comment: +1 & "answered" for pointing out the onOptionsItemSelected, though.  I'm just now updating an app I first wrote several SDKs ago and that is, in fact, how it was done when I wrote the app and so you explained why all my other activities are working as expected.

Comment: @Paul you get a warning for `parentActivityName` attribute, but older APIs still successfully use your meta-tag. Glad you solved it by the way.

Comment: It's not a warning, it's a red X.